# Combinations from prime number of elements

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

*Let $p$ be a prime and let $k$ be a natural number:
Prove that for $k < p$, $\binom{p}{k}$ is divisible by $p$.*

My proof:

The formula for $p$ choose $k$ is:

$$\frac{p!}{k!(p-k)!}$$

Since the factorial $p! = p * (p-1) * (p-2)... * 2 * 1$ it contains the prime number $p$. This number cannot cancelled out by the denominator since only $p$ and $1$ divide $p$. Therefore

$$\frac{p!}{k!(p-k)!}$$
altogether must be divisible by $p$, as it will contain the multiplicand $p$.

Is this reasonable?

Comment: Yes, it's fine (though many of us would object mildly to the author's terminology, since we consider $0$ a natural number).

Comment: Most books I have do NOT consider $0\in \mathbb{N}$ They define $\mathbb{N}\cup \{0\}$ to be the whole numbers, if they mention it at all. I think the naturals are much nicer without $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Broadly speaking you are correct.

Personally I would say that $p$ divides $p!$, but if $0 \lt k \lt p $ then since $p$ is prime $p$ does not divide $k!$ or $(p-k)!$ and so  does not divide their product $k!(p-k)!$.